# TMemoryStream.ReadBuffer throws Access Violation exception

Tags: delphi

I try to read the first 16 bytes that are loaded into a Memorystream to a TBytes. This ReadBuffer methot throws an access violation exception.

I want to load encrypted data from a file. The first 16 bytes are the MD5 hash of the password used to create the file. So the first thing that I want to do after loading, is checking if the provided password matches with the encoded saved one. To do that, I reintroduced the LoadFromFile method as a function, returning a loading code.
For testing now, my file only contains the 16 bytes for the password.
I checked if the MemoryStream is properly created, which it is. Looking in the Local Variables, I see that indeed 16 bytes are loaded into the Stream.

```pascal
  TEncMemoryStream = class(TMemoryStream)
    strict private
      PwdMD5: TBytes;
.
.
    public
      constructor Create;
      destructor Destroy;override;
      function LoadFromFile(Filename: String;PassWord:String): 
             TLoadResult;reintroduce;

.
.
function TEncMemoryStream.LoadFromFile(Filename: String;PassWord:String): TLoadResult;
begin
  Result := lrLoaded;
  try
    inherited LoadFromFile(Filename);
    ReadBuffer(PwdMD5,16);      // <----- here the exception is thrown
  except
    Result := lrFailed;
  end;
  if Result = lrLoaded then
    if not CheckPassWord(PassWord) then begin
      Clear;
      Result := lrWrongPwd;
    end
end;
```

I tried other Read functions as well, they all throw the same error (which makes totally sense as they all eventually call the TStream.Read method).

Does someone have a clue as to why this exception is thrown and what I can do to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried resetting the stream's Position to 0 before reading from it?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reaction MartynA. I just checked and the stupidest thing happened. I didn't set the length of the TBytes. If I set it to 16, it works a s charm...

Comment: `ReadBuffer` expects an already allocated buffer. Is your `PwdMD5` at least 16 bytes long? Then you can call `ReadBuffer(PwdMD5[0], 16);`

Answer (score 8):

PwdMD5 is nil by default. IOW, you need to call SetLength(PwdMD5, 16) in order to have someplace to for the bytes to go when reading the file.